# Sublime Text 3: Drag & Drop, Move & Create a copy of files & folders

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

Is it possible to Drag & Drop, Move & Create a copy of files & folders from within Sublime Text?

I can rename, delete and have a plugin so that I can reveal in finder, but no other functionality from the project inspector sidebar.

Maybe it is me being really silly, but surely this should be one of the most obvious features?

Answer (score 138, accepted):

Obvious feature is not implemented, though I suggest you to use [Sidebar Enhancements](https://github.com/titoBouzout/SideBarEnhancements), a really great plugin to manage the sidebar stuff in ST2/3. (Jul. 24, 2017: Only ST3 as the repo notes)

Though it may seem obvious, but the sidebar is really poor in sublime text. There are requests on the official *userecho* page about that like [this one](http://sublimetext.userecho.com/topic/130561-drag-n-drop-files-from-the-filesystem-into-the-sidebar/).

I'm sure it will be implemented some time later. You also should not forget, that sublime is keyboard-oriented editor, as Vim was. That's something rare these days and is a feature. You may bind everything to keyboard or implement yourself using build systems and plugins.

Comment: Vlakarados - You mention Sublime's keyboard-orientation. I like the idea of drag-and-drop in the sidebar, but would also like to know how to move files between folders using the keyboard. Do you know if there are keyboard commands for selecting and moving files in the sidebar?

Comment: @KurtWM indeed there are https://github.com/wulftone/sublime-text-quick-file-move If you're familiar with python you may write almost anything that's not using the sublime text window and it's elements, for them you have a somewhat limited API.

Comment: @KurtWM I've just noticed, you can actually move files via sidebar enhancements package as well (stated by the package owner I linked in the previous comment)

Comment: I tried to install this using package manager but do not see it in the list, I was looking for sidebar enhancements

Comment: ALso is this possible in Sublime Text 2?

Comment: @pal4life as I remember, it's not available for ST2 anymore, you may browse the repository on GitHub and clone the package manually, if it doesn't work, you will have to manually find the revision that was for the ST2 and revert your history to that one.

Comment: i have also though about this problem in sublime and a bit happy other have been annoyed with it as well.

Answer (score 1):

delete the file(s) you wish to move then drag and drop from the recycling bin to the folder you wish to move them to. make sure it **doesn't permanently** delete your file before you do this.

Comment: This answer is super cool! On `macOS` you can do it by opening target folder in `Finder` :)